# Weird MAMP Pro CSS caching issue

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

In the MAMP working directory, I made a change to a CSS file a week or two ago.  Every once in a while, the change stops working.  If I open up the link to the CSS file in the browser, I see the change has been reverted to the old file.  If I refresh the page, it properly updates, and then everything works ok again… for a few hours.  Then it reverts back to the old CSS file, and I have to manually refresh it again.  I have no idea where this cached version is being stored or why it's replacing the updated version.  This has been going on for over a week, and I've restarted both the browser and MAMP with no luck.  I've also Googled the issue with no luck.  Has anyone seen anything like this before?